# Working of NMOS as a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, analog, nmos, physical-design

I came across instances where NMOS was used as a capacitor in analog circuits. This is done by shorting the drain and source. The drain/source acts as one terminal of the capacitor while gate acts as the other terminal, as shown below. 
[image]
Here are some observations about its working:

1) This acts like a capacitor if drain/source terminal is connected to ground. If drain/source is connected to VDD, its as good as open (0 capacitance)
2) To get a good capacitance value when drain/source is grounded, we have to use a large length and small width for the NMOS

Now, I am trying to reason out these observations.

1) I guess that when drain/source is grounded, the gate oxide acts like the capacitor with n-doped regions providing the charges. But what happens when drain/source is set to VDD. Why can't it still act like a capacitor between gate and the body?

2) How to reason out the need for large length and small width? I guess it is to reduce the effect of overlap caps between the gate and drain/source. But I am not able to arrive at a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

*If drain/source is connected to VDD, its as good as open (0 capacitance)*

**That is not true**, you get **less** capacitance but not zero.

*How to reason out the need for large length and small width?*

Also a wrong assumption, **any** size of MOSFET will work as a capacitor. The series resistance of the capacitor is generally smaller (you get a "better" capacitor) when the width is large and length is small. But in practice I usually make these MOS capacitors (somewhat) square as that is a good compromise between series resistance and capacitance per area.

Comment: Some semiconductor processes allow the layout to have "capacitor" labels placed on the FETS; during processing, those FETs will have the region between Source-and--Drain altered with extra doping, and the threshold voltage is shifted away from normal values; this shifted-Vthreshold  gives a more-constant gate-bulk (gate-tub, gate-well) V_C curve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bimpelrekkie and analogsystemsrf. But I'm not able to visualise clearly how length and width relate to the series resistance as well as the capacitance ( for instance which has higher capacitance, nmos with larger length or one with larger width)

Comment: The capacitance is mostly related to the **gate area** of the MOSFET, so width x length. Series resistance is more complex, the silicon substrate has some resistance so if you contact it with a larger area (long drains and sources meaning a wide MOSFET) then series resistance becomes smaller.